Throttling queries/requests in HotChoclate GraphQL in .NET
Is there a way I can ratelimit graphql queries? I'm using HotChocolate for setting up the graphql server in .Net 8.
I need to do this in a distributed environment. I'm currently using an AspNetCoreRateLimit library which has a in-built redis connection to keep track of the request count. But the issue with this is I can limit only the /graphql endpoint and not different queries that are fired to this endpoint meaning ther ratelimit will apply to all the queries.

Did you check out the IBM Cost Spec comming in Hot Chocolate 14?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6Rq4kU_GfM
It is comming out in a few daysn (hopefully), but there are already some release candidates.
